# Issue with continuously run of getJSON function

Tags: javascript, json, getjson, jqxhr

I'm trying to print Google last quotes with the code below.
The problem is that it prints only 1 quote and it seems like it stops running.
What could be a problem here?
Thanks
Danny

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var symbol = 'goog';

    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22"+symbol+"%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json";

    while (1 == 1) {
        var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function (json)
        {
            var lastquote = json.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly;
            document.write("lastquote = " + lastquote + "<br>");
        })
          .done(function() {
            document.write( "success<br>" );
          })
          .fail(function() {
            document.write( "error<br>" );
          })
          .always(function() {S
            document.write( "complete<br>" );
          });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `while(true)` to run infinite loops. I visualized the object and it is ok. So you got one result for google. Now you try to make **DDOS** attack to yahoo with that code. Trying to fetch data for every cpu cycle is insane, yahoo notices that and stops you because you eat their resources very much. You better use a **setInterval** function to do your ajax call. It may vary from 1 to 5 seconds. I don't know if this api has limits.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that AJAX calls are **asynchronous**, so you are basically making infinite requests to that url!
It will probably hang your browser in few seconds, use a timeout and execute the function again when the previous has finished, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                    var symbol = 'goog';

                    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22"+symbol+"%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json";

                    ajaxRequest(url);

                    });


function ajaxRequest(url) {
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function (json)
            {
            var lastquote = json.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly;
            document.write("lastquote = " + lastquote + "<br>");
            window.setTimeout(function() { ajaxRequest(url); }, 1000);
            })
    .done(function() {
            document.write( "success<br>" );
            })
    .fail(function() {
            document.write( "error<br>" );
            })
    .always(function() {
            document.write( "complete<br>" );
            });
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in a very wrong way!!!

The code what you have written here.. will infinitely start sending requests to server. So your case within `while( 1==1 )` is actually executing it's block thousands time in a second.

You have actually initiated thousands of requests instantly and `$.getJSON(url, ...);` as already fired.

You should send another request when one has completed, something this way...

```
function requestData(){
    $.getJSON(url)
        .done(function(){
            // Do your stuff
            // ...
            // and call requestData again
            requestData();
        }).
        fail(function(){
            // Handle Errors
            // ...
            // and call requestData again
            requestData();
        });
}
// Call for first time.
requestData();
```

This way one your one request has completed ( failed / succeeded ). It'll fire another request and so on..